# Typeset matrices over several lines using IEEEeqnarray

Tags: equations, matrices

Here is my MWE. I would like to have the first three objects (things separated by equality sign) on the first line, and the last object on the next line, because it won't fit nicely next to the first three. I have tried changing it in several ways, and it used to complain `missing $ inserted`, but now it is complaining `missing \endgroup inserted`. I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. I am worried it is muddled between the & in the matrices and the & in the `eqnarray`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}


\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rcl}
A^TA &= \begin{pmatrix}
a  & d & 0\\
b & e & 0\\
0 & 0 & \pm 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a  & b & 0\\
d & e & 0\\
0 & 0 & \pm 1  \end{pmatrix} &=  \begin{pmatrix}
a^2+d^2 & ab+de & 0\\
ab+de & b^2+e^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
&=  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make several changes: use `{rCl}` instead of `{rcl}` to define the setup, and write `=` instead of `&=` to generate the second equality symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % not 'amsthm'
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}    
A^TA &=& \begin{pmatrix}
         a & d & 0\\
         b & e & 0\\
         0 & 0 & \pm 1 
         \end{pmatrix} 
         \begin{pmatrix}
         a & b & 0\\
         d & e & 0\\
         0 & 0 & \pm 1  
         \end{pmatrix} 
      = \begin{pmatrix}
         a^2+d^2 & ab+de & 0\\
         ab+de & b^2+e^2 & 0\\
         0 & 0 & 1 
         \end{pmatrix} \\
     &=& \begin{pmatrix}
         1 & 0 & 0\\
         0 & 1 & 0\\
         0 & 0 & 1  
         \end{pmatrix}.
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

I suggest to use `amsmath` or `mathtools` (which improve `amsmath`) instead of `IEEEtrantools` and instead of `IEEEeqnarray*` use `aligned` environment from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lipsum}% added for dummy text which demonstrate two column text

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[11]
\[
\begin{aligned}
A^TA 
    & = \begin{pmatrix}
            a  & d & 0      \\
             & e & 0        \\
            0 & 0 & \pm 1   
        \end{pmatrix} 
        \begin{pmatrix}
            a  & b & 0      \\
               & e & 0      \\
               & 0 & \pm 1    
        \end{pmatrix}   \\
    & = \begin{pmatrix}
            a^2+d^2 & ab+de   & 0 \\
            ab+de   & b^2+e^2 & 0 \\
            0       & 0       & 1 
        \end{pmatrix}    
      = \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 & 0  \\
            0 & 1 & 0  \\
            0 & 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
\]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Is there some special reason to use `IEEEeqnarray`? Since you use some other AMS  packages I don't see any obstacle why not to use `amsmath` too.

Comment: The `IEEEeqnarray` environment is very flexible and highly customizable. With it, certain layouts are more easily achievable than with the `amsmath` machinery.

Comment: @Mico, probably it is. It is long time when I last time use it. I have in remembrance, that at that time I have a filling that its use is more complicated than use of AMS packages. It seems that I need read its documentation again. Than you for point.

Comment: It should be `\lipsum*[11]`, so the excess space above the display would not show: `\lipsum` inserts an unwanted `\par`.